# CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT

Tags: php, libcurl

```
Error code 28
```

Using the same code on my local machine works perfectly.

But when I send the same code to my preprod environment, I got a timeout error 28. I have also set the timeout to 60 seconds. Same error.

I have checked error logs + my symfony logs but in vain.

```
  $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://'. $ftp['ftp']. '/'. $filename);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $ftp['username']. ':'. $ftp['password']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        echo  curl_errno($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a little digging, I have found that the web server does not allow outgoing request for any ftp. I had to ask the web hosting to allow outgoing request to this particular ftp and everything works fine now.